# Dplyr on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm trying to filter out rows in a dataset:

`head(data)`

```
  event bp_no  sample chrom      bp       gene    feature type length
1     1   bp1 NA54522    1 2425901 intergenic intergenic  INV    0.1
2     1   bp2 NA54522    1 2426025 intergenic intergenic  INV    0.1
3     3   bp1 NA54522    1 6694426        Tsp     intron  INV    0.1
4     3   bp2 NA54522    1 6694566        Tsp     intron  INV    0.1
5     6   bp1 NA54522    2 8387755       pdm3     intron  INV    0.2
6     6   bp2 NA54522    2 8387927       pdm3     exon_2  INV    0.2
```

To remove rows where the chromosome is `13` and the bp >= `2000000` and <= `400000`

In Perl I would do this:

```
if ($chrom eq '13' and $bp >= 2000000 and $bp <= 400000){
      next;
    }
```

I want to do this using the dplyr package. I can **keep** all the rows that meet this condition using:

```
data<-filter(data, chrom == "13" & bp > 2000000 & bp <= 400000)
```

But I can't work out out how to either remove them, or to keep all rows that **don't** meet this condition

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter` with negate (`!`)

```
data %>%
       filter(!(chrom == 13 & bp >= 2000000 & bp <= 400000))
```

Comment: I was trying with `!(data, chrom == "13" & bp > 2000000 & bp <= 400000)` but it wasn't working. Does this have to be done using pipes?

Comment: @fugu You didn't had `filter` nor `subset` in the command.  If you need it to be without pipes, `filter(data, !(chrom==13 & bp >=2000000 & bp <= 400000))`

Comment: what do you mean? My command was `data<-filter(data, chrom == "13" & bp > 2000000 & bp <= 400000)`

Comment: @fugu  In the previous comment, you didn't show `filter`